# Print not working when compiled with py2exe

Tags: python, printing, py2exe

this is my very simple code, printing argvs:

```
import sys

argv=sys.argv
for each in sys.argv:
    print each
```

here's the output when ran:

```
e:\python>python test1.py 1 2 3 4 5
test1.py
1
2
3
4
5
```

I want it to be compiled, so I made one with py2exe:

```
e:\python>python setup.py py2exe
```

and my setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 3}},
    windows = [{'script': "test1.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

and I don't get any output when I run my program by test1.exe 1 2 3 4 5 or with any other argvs. sys.argvs should be a list with at least one object(test1.exe) in it, therefore I think I have misunderstandings with print function of python.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? I just want everything to be printed to commandline. I program from linux, but windows users should be using my program.

thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
# ...
windows = [{'script': "test1.py"}],
#...
```

`windows` option is used to create GUI executables, which suppresses console output. Use `console` instead:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 3}},
    console = [{'script': "test1.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```