# Output missing when exe built with py2exe is run from Win CLI

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I have a script, `my_script.py` that includes these functions.

```
def output_results(scrub_count, insert_count):
    print "Scrubbing Complete" 
    print "Valid requests: "+ str(scrub_count["Success"])
    if scrub_count["Error"] > 0:
        print "Requests with errors can be found in " + error_log
    print "\n"
    print "Inserting Complete"    
    print str(insert_count["Success"]) + " rows inserted into " + table + "."
    print str(insert_count["Error"]) + " rows were NOT inserted. Please see " + error_log + " for more details."

def main():
    scrub_count={"Success":0,"Error":0}
    insert_count={"Success":0,"Error":0}

    someOtherFunctions()

    output_results(scrub_count, insert_count)
```

When I run the `python my_script.py` from the Windows CLI, `output_results` prints out the following as expected.

```
Scrubbing Complete
Valid requests: 7
Invalid requests: 3
Requests with errors can be found in error.log

Inserting Complete
5 rows inserted into Table.
2 rows were NOT inserted. Please see error.log for more details.
```

I then build `my_script.py` into `my_script.exe` using py2exe and this setup file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe':{'bundle_files':1, 'compressed':True,'includes':["socket","decimal","uuid"]}},
    windows = [{'script':"C:\Path\To\my_script.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

When I run `my_script.exe` from the Windows CLI, it functions properly *except* for the fact that `output_results` does not output anything to the command line like when I run `python my_script.py`.

- How can I fix this and still only have a single executable created?
- I haven't tried pyinstaller or cx_freeze. Do these handle options handle this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously explained by @Avaris in [Print not working when compiled with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505383/print-not-working-when-compiled-with-py2exe) - `windows` option  in setup section is intended to build GUI executables, which do not handle printing to console. The proper option is to use `console` section.

So, instead of

```
setup(
    options = {'py2exe':{'bundle_files':1, 'compressed':True,'includes':["socket","decimal","uuid"]}},
    windows = [{'script':"C:\Path\To\my_script.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

use

```
setup(
    options = {'py2exe':{'bundle_files':1, 'compressed':True,'includes':["socket","decimal","uuid"]}},
    console = [{'script': "C:\Path\To\my_script.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

I can't say for cx_freeze, but pyinstaller also has separate routines for compiling into gui and console executables.